# Get Feature-flag Values before Cypress spec compiled

Tags: angular, cypress, cloudbees, rollout

I'm attempting to run cypress tests dynamically based on flag values from cloudbees' feature flags. something like this:

```js
if (flags.foo.isEnabled()) {
  describe(`When 'foo' feature-flag is enabled`, () => {
    it(`Then foo element should exist`, () => {});
  });
} else {
  describe(`When 'foo' feature-flag is disabled`, () => {
    it(`Then foo element should not exist`, () => {});
  });
}
```

however, more often than not, all `describe`s are compiled for the spec before the feature flag values are determined. when the `it`s are finally run, those flag values *have* been determined, and so the test will fail (if the actual flag values are true).

I can't figure out how to get cypress to wait for the flag values to come back before it compiles the spec file into tests.

I get the impression that setting up requesting the flag values in a plug-in is the way to go, but i can't think of how to force the exports function to wait.

Comment: Can you show how `flags` is obtained? If it is async you could await it in an async `before()` function.

Comment: Maybe try this? https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-select-tests

Comment: @SteveZodiac it's a web request and thus async, but cypress doesn't wait for it to complete before it chugs along compiling the tests.

Comment: @olore thanks, i'll look into it.